# Question about the integral of $1/(1+9x^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration

This might be a stupid question but what is the integral of $\frac{1}{1 + 9x^2}$? I want to think it's $\tan^{-1}(3x) + c$ but the book I'm working in says $\frac{1}{3}\tan^{-1}(3x) + c$.

How did they get $1/3$?

Comment: Note that you integrate anything at wolframalpha (google it), then click show steps, and it will give you the step by step instructions for integrating!

Comment: @Fdart: This is not particularly good advice. You didn't even answer --or even address in any way-- OP's question, which has a very straightforward answer if you just think about it rather than re-route yourself automatically to a computation tools...

Comment: You can always check to see if your answer is correct by differentiation. If you differentiate $\tan^{-1}(3x)+C$, you'll get$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\tan^{-1}(3x)+\right) = \left(\frac{1}{1+(3x)^2}\right)(3x)' = \frac{3}{1+9x^2}.$$So your answer is off by a factor of $3$.

Comment: @Fdart: in this case show steps in Alpha yields nothing.  You get the integral, but no steps.  But it is a reasonable thing to try first, and for OP to indicate that s/he OP has tried it and doesn't understand.

Answer (score 11):

Set $u=3x$. Then the integrand is $1/(1+u^2)$ which integrates to $\tan^{-1} u$ but $du=3dx$. This gives you the $1/3$.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to think about this question is to differentiate $\tan^{-1}(3x) + C$ and see what you get.  Using the chain rule, 
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \tan^{-1}(3x) + C \right ) = \frac{3}{1 + (3x)^2} = \frac{3}{1 + 9x^2}.
$$

Thus the correct antiderivative of 
$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+9x^2}
$$ 
must include a factor of $1/3$ to compensate: 
$$
\displaystyle \frac{1}{3} \tan^{-1}(3x) + C.
$$

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating a bit more on the above hints in a more clear flow.

So we are trying to integrate the following expression $~~~\rightarrow ~~~ \displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{1+9x^{2}}\ dx$.

To do the this, we will need to make an appropriate substitution inside of the integrand and to make the $9x^{2}$ look like something equivalent. Doing this leads us to the following:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{1+(3x)^{2}}\ dx$

Let: $~u=3x$

$du=3 dx$

$dx=\dfrac{1}{3}\ du$

Substituting in *u* and *dx* we see that we get the following:

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\displaystyle \dfrac{1}{3} \int \dfrac{1}{1+(u)^{2}}\ du$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=~\dfrac{1}{3} \text{arctan}(u)+C$

$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~=~\dfrac{1}{3} \text{arctan}(3x)+C~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\blacksquare$

So as we can see, the $\dfrac{1}{3}$ came from the substitution we made and then going from there and solving for what *dx* represented in terms of *u*.

Hope this helped out. Let me know if you have any questions on any of the steps made in this process.

Thanks.

Good Luck.